# Why is React client connecting to Socket server twice?

Tags: reactjs, socket.io, vite

Whenever I connect my client or reload the browser the io on ('connection') runs twice.

https://github.com/gpk96gpk/ticTacToe

I've tried running it without strict mode, cleaning up the use effect and compiling it but it still runs twice. Is there a way I could manually assign a player1 and player2 with the double connection?

server/index.ts

```
import express from 'express';
import { createServer } from "http";
import { Server } from 'socket.io';

const app = express();
const httpServer = createServer(app);
const io = new Server(httpServer, {
  cors: {
    origin: "http://localhost:5173",
  }
});

type GameStateType = [string, string, string, string, string, string, string, string, string];

let isXTurn: Boolean;
let gameState:GameStateType = ['','','','','','','','',''];
const players = {};
const victoryConditions = [
  [0, 1, 2],
  [3, 4, 5],
  [6, 7, 8],
  [0, 3, 6],
  [1, 4, 7],
  [2, 5, 8],
  [0, 4, 8],
  [2, 4, 6]
];

io.on('connection', (socket) => {
  isXTurn = true;
  let gameOver = false;
  gameState = ['','','','','','','','',''];

  console.log(`User connected with ID: ${socket.id}`);

  console.log(socket.rooms); // Set { <socket.id> }
  socket.join("room1");
  console.log(socket.rooms);

  if (!players[socket.id]) {
    players[socket.id] = socket.id;
    console.log(players);
  }

  socket.on('tileClicked', (id) => {
    gameState[id] = isXTurn ? 'X' : 'O';
    for (let i = 0; i < victoryConditions.length; i++) {
      const condition = victoryConditions[i];
      if (gameState[condition[0]] === gameState[condition[1]] && gameState[condition[1]] === gameState[condition[2]] && gameState[condition[0]] !== '') {
        console.log('game over');
        socket.broadcast.emit('gameOver', true);
        gameOver = true;
      }
    }
    console.log(id);
    console.log(isXTurn);
    console.log('gameOver?'+gameOver);
    socket.emit('turnChange', isXTurn);
    socket.broadcast.emit('turnChange', isXTurn);
    if (gameOver) {
      isXTurn = undefined;
    } else {
      isXTurn = !isXTurn;
    }
  });
});

httpServer.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log('server running at http://localhost:3000');
});
```

client/TicTacToe.ts

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react"
import Board from "./Board"
import GameOver from "./GameOver"
import Reset from "./Reset"
import { io } from "socket.io-client"

const socket = io("http://localhost:3000")


const TicTacToe = () => {
    const [gameOver, setGameOver] = useState(false);
    const [xTurn, setXTurn] = useState(Boolean);
    const [letterIcon, setLetterIcon] = useState('fa-solid fa-x fa-5x');
    const [isClicked, setIsClicked] = useState(false);
    const [winner, setWinner] = useState<string | null>(null);


    useEffect(() => {
        if (gameOver && winner === null) {
            setWinner(!xTurn ? 'X' : 'O');
        }
    }, [gameOver, xTurn, winner]);

    useEffect(() => {
        const gameOver = (arg: React.SetStateAction<boolean>) => {
            setGameOver(arg);
            console.log("gameOver")
        }

        socket.on("gameOver", gameOver);
        return () => { socket.off("gameOver", gameOver) }  
    }, [gameOver]);

    useEffect(() => {
        const turnChange = (arg: React.SetStateAction<boolean>) => {
            console.log("turnChange")
            console.log(arg)
            setXTurn(arg);
            if (arg === null && gameOver) {
                setLetterIcon('hidden');
            }
            if (isClicked && arg !== null && !gameOver) {
                setLetterIcon(!arg ? 'fa-solid fa-x fa-5x' : 'fa-solid fa-o fa-5x');
            } else {
                setLetterIcon('hidden');
            }
        }
        socket.on("turnChange", turnChange);
        return () => { socket.off("turnChange", turnChange) }
    }, [gameOver, isClicked, xTurn]);

    return (
    <div className="ticTacToe">
        <h1>Tic Tac Toe</h1>
        <GameOver isGameOver={gameOver} gameWinner={winner}/>
        <Reset />
        <Board letterIcon={letterIcon} setIsClicked={setIsClicked} gameOver={gameOver}/>
    </div>
    )
}

export default TicTacToe
```

client/TicTacToeContext.tsx

```
import {createContext, useState} from 'react';
import { TicTacToeContextProps } from '../types/tictactoe';
import { io } from 'socket.io-client';


const socket = io("http://localhost:3000")

export const TicTacToeContext = createContext({
    isXTurn: true,
})


export const TicTacToeContextProvider: React.FC<TicTacToeContextProps> = (props) => {
    const [isXTurn, setIsXTurn] = useState(true)

    socket.on('changeTurn', (isPlayerTurn) => {
        setIsXTurn(isPlayerTurn);
    })

    return (
        <TicTacToeContext.Provider value={{ isXTurn }}>
            {props.children}
        </TicTacToeContext.Provider>
    );
}
```

client/Tile.tsx

```
import { TileProps } from "../types/tictactoe"

const Tile = ({ id, letterIcon, handleClick, children }: TileProps) => {
    
    return (
        <div id={String(id)} className={'tile'} onClick={handleClick}>
            <i className={ letterIcon }></i>
            {children}
        </div>
    )

}

export default Tile
```

client/Board.tsx

```
import { useState } from 'react';
import Tile from './Tile';
import { io } from 'socket.io-client';
import { BoardTypes } from '../types/tictactoe';
const socket = io('http://localhost:3000')


const Board:React.FC<BoardTypes> = ({letterIcon, isClicked, setIsClicked, gameOver}) => {
    const [tileStates, setTileStates] = useState(Array(9).fill(null));
    
    const handleTileClick = (index: number) => {
        const newTileStates = [...tileStates];
        const allNull = tileStates.every(element => element === null);
        console.log('handleTileClick')
        console.log('isClicked'+isClicked)
        console.log('allNull'+allNull)
        if (!newTileStates[index] || allNull) {
            !gameOver && setIsClicked(true);
            newTileStates[index] = letterIcon;
            setTileStates(newTileStates);
            socket.emit('tileClicked', index);
            console.log(index)
        }
    }

    return (
        <>
            <div className="board">
                {tileStates.map((tileLetterIcon, index) => (
                    <Tile letterIcon={tileLetterIcon} key={index} setIsClicked={setIsClicked} isClicked={isClicked} handleClick={() => handleTileClick(index)} />
                ))}
            </div>
        </>
    );
                }
export default Board;
```

Comment: please provide a minimum reproducible example.